# After Windows installation, no Linux bootup choice?

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, multi-boot

I have been setting up my computer for work, which runs Linux Ubuntu, and we use a lot of programs etc. so it has taken a day or two to get it all ready.

I was going to have a dual boot with a Windows 7 partition as well. I installed Windows 7 and set that up. Now, when I boot up the system, I can't choose Ubuntu anymore.

Anyone know a quick fix, or do I have to start all over again?

Okay have tried 2 guides now... none worked, can someone give me step by step, info i think you need:

Linux = ubuntu 12.04
windows 7
Partition with linux = sda1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reinstall GRUB from the Linux LiveCD. You can read more about it, for example, here:

http://www.increa.com/articles/GRUB-over-windows/

And yes, it's not a programming related question, it's about system administration.

Answer (score 2):

It's the windows installer that silently wiped your first disc's MBR.
This is where GRUB loader was installed before, now it contains the MS NTLDR loader instead.

As previously said by other answers you have to reinstall GRUB starting from a Linux rescure CD, ubuntu or any other linux CD/DVD capable of mounting your disc partitions.

The procedure depends on the rescue disc, but generally it's:

1. start the linux rescue disc
2. mount your / partition
3. chroot your new / filesystem
4. mount /proc, /sys and /dev virtual filesystems
5. mount /boot (if it's a dedicated FS)
6. reinstall GRUB on your starting HDD's MBR
7. umount anything
8. reboot the system without the rescue disc
9. choose "linux" from the list of options :-) (joking)
10. uninstall windows :-) :-) :-) (joking again, don't do it if you not need to!)

Comment: Think i just screwed up even more.. did mount my linux to /media/root
and then i did chroot /media/root . Now it cant run fdisk -l anymore

Comment: [NTLDR has been replaced with BOOTMGR/winload.exe on Vista and newer (NT 6.0 and newer)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLDR#History)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reinstall the boot loader from an install/rescue Ubuntu disk.

Answer (score 0):

I have conceived a solution, hope it helps.

1. Install wingrub (grub for windows, hope that works for win 7), which allows multi booting on windows. Be sure to install it in C:\
2. Edit your wingrub conf to add your ubuntu booting lines to its boot options. Get the lines which you should add to the conf file in the following way:

   1. Boot from your linux rescue disk.
   2. Mount your linux /.
   3. Copy the lines which boots your ubuntu from /etc/grub.conf
   4. Add these lines to your wingrub conf.